# How do I add an img to a fixed footer with a z-index: -1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fixed

```css
.w-map {
 background-image: url("../# BootstrapTheme #/img/world-map.II.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position:center bottom; 
}
.footer {
 min-height: 506px;
 background-color: #f8f8f8 !important;
 position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
 border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

Also with the background image not working the css background color doesn't work either.

```html
<div class="footer w-map">
  <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
    </div>                
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your snippet is just an empty window. Give us a working demo, so that we can help.

Comment: z-index: -1; puts your div behind it's parent so no matter what you put in it, it won't be visible. Unless the parent div has a z-index: smaller than -1.

Comment: basically what I am trying to achieve is have a fixed footer that is hidden from view until the main content end scrolls to the top of the footer height, and I have achieved that. But I want to put a png as the background of the footer which I cant seem to get lol